# Adding friction to joints

Tags: drake

I am setting up a simulation with some revolute and prismatic joints (fairly simple robot arm), and I was wondering if there is a straightforward way to add friction to the arm's joints?

Something simple like a coefficient of static friction and a coefficient of kinetic friction, and switching between the two based on the joint's velocity.

In the sim I just have gravity as an external force and then a PID controller controlling the joint positions and velocities. The way I see it, I could add friction to the joints by either:

1. Hacking together a torque to apply by looking at the gravity and actuation forces at each time step
2. Writing a new joint class that inherits from the linear/revolute joint classes and add in some sort of friction

Do either of these seem like the best way to do this? I'm hoping there's an easier way I am missing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The joints (e.g., [RevoluteJoint](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1multibody_1_1_revolute_joint.html)) already offer `damping`:

*Viscous damping coefficient, in N⋅m⋅s, used to model losses within the joint. The damping torque (in N⋅m) is modeled as `τ = -damping⋅ω`, i.e., opposing motion, with ω the angular rate for `this` joint.*

It can be set via the API or in [SDFormat](http://sdformat.org/spec?ver=1.9&elem=joint), e.g.,

```xml
      <joint name="revolute_joint" type="revolute">
        <child>link2</child>
        <parent>link1</parent>
        <axis>
          <xyz expressed_in="__model__">0 0 1</xyz>
          <limit>
            <lower>-1</lower>
            <upper>2</upper>
            <effort>100</effort>
            <velocity>100</velocity>
            <drake:acceleration>200</drake:acceleration>
          </limit>
          <dynamics>
            <damping>0.2</damping>
            <spring_reference>0</spring_reference>
            <spring_stiffness>0</spring_stiffness>
          </dynamics>
        </axis>
      </joint>
```

Is that a close enough match for what you need?

Comment: Not really although this is definitely helpful when trying to set up a friction model. I was really hoping for a static friction force/torque that must be overcome to induce movement, and then a kinectic friction model with a constant force/torque and a term that scales with velocity (which the damping should be able to do). I was kind of surprised to see this isn't a built-in feature of the simulator as I feel like friction is a pretty standard physics property

Comment: I guess they do have [coulomb friction for surface interactions](https://drake.mit.edu/pydrake/pydrake.multibody.plant.html?highlight=coulomb#pydrake.multibody.plant.CoulombFriction) so I could have potentially modeled the entire joint with 3D models and simulated that way?

Comment: Coulomb friction for internal-coordinate joints is much harder to implement than Coulomb friction at a surface contact, and we don't currently have it. Modeling the joint as a contact would give you real friction there, but could come with other troubles!

Comment: The problem is that friction is normal-force dependent and we don't have an easy way to determine the normal force at an internal-coordinate joint. For a revolute joint (for example) we have to calculate the radial component of the reaction force to compute the joint friction, but that reaction is coupled (linearly) to the friction. A reasonable alternative is to time-delay the reaction force by a step (capturing it into a discrete state variable) and then use the time t-1 reaction to compute the time t friction as a Drake force element.

Answer (score 1):

For revolute joints, what is needed is a frictional torque  that depends on |ₙ| (the magnitude of a force on the joint), a material-dependent coefficient of friction μₖ, and an effective radius rₑ. During sliding, the direction of the frictional torque  is opposite the relevant angular velocity vector .  To avoid a divide by zero problem when  = , add an epsilon ε that is a small positive number that represents a very small || (magnitude of angular velocity).

= -μₖ * rₑ * |ₙ| *  / (|| + ε)

Note: Sometimes the coefficient of friction μₖ and effective radius rₑ are combined into a single constant.

Note: I do not unambiguously understand the SDF spec. I can guess, but that seems somewhat antagonist to a specification.
http://sdformat.org/spec?ver=1.9&elem=joint#axis_dynamics

Comment: Conveniently for a revolute joint the angular velocity is just a scalar so all we care about is the sign! Also in general normal force ₙ is dependent on  which makes implementation awkward. In cases where we can assume ₙ is roughly constant the user could supply some scalar=μₖrₑ|ₙ| to use for friction, maybe that is what the sdf expects?